# rest content not appearing in Xamarin.forms examples

Tags: rest, xamarin.forms

I am experimenting with two of the examples ToDoRest and the XamarinForms3RestApiApp. I am looking specifically at the UWP client.

I have made sure that I have the same code on my computer as the examples in GIT.

When I run them they compile without error and the form comes up. However in both examples the  existing data from the rest backend does not appear as content on the UWP page. clicking on the api link shows that the json formatted data does come up when accessed directly

In both cases its the 'vanilla' example on GIT -nothing changed.

Has anyone else experienced this on these examples?If so, what might be preventing data from showing?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  Have you used the debugger to verify that your API calls are returning data?  Have you stepped through the code to verify it is executing correctly?

Comment: Thanks -Normally I do post code- but in this case the code in its entirety is on git. Just downloaded and compiled as is. I'll need to debug further specific to the api call. At this point it was just seeing whether others had similar 'vanilla' experience with those samples. thanks